# Best way to extend Laravel Vendor packages?

Tags: php, laravel

What is the best way to extend laravel vendor packages?

1 - Copy package to My own App/packages and changing it?

2 - Using Service Providers to extend classes?

3 - or something else?

Answer (score 1):

There is no best way but `option - 1` is not a choice, not at all, at least for extending a component/class.

Anyways, The Laravel framework provides different ways for extending it's own packages. Foe example, the framework has several `Manager classes` that manage the creation of driver-based components. These include `the cache`, `session`, `authentication`, and `queue` components. The manager class is responsible for creating a particular driver implementation based on the application's configuration.

Each of these managers includes an extend method which may be used to easily inject new driver resolution functionality into the manager.In this case, you can extend the `cache`, for example, using something like this:

```
Cache::extend('mongo', function($app)
{
    return Cache::repository(new MongoStore);
});
```

But that's not all but an way to extending the component using the manager. Like you mentioned about `Service Provider`, yes, that's another option for extending a component. In this case you are able to extend the component's service provider class and swap the providers array as well. There is a dedicated chapter on Laravel website, please check [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/extending).

Answer (score 0):

The vendor files are normally namespaced.  Your own package/code will/should be namespaced too.  Using this, I would create my own package with a dependency on the other Vendor's package, and then create my own class that extends theirs.

```
<?php namespace My\Namespace\Models
class MyClass extends \Vendor3\Package\VendorClass {
  // my custom code that enhances the vendor class
}
```

You should never be considering changing a vendor's package.  While this can be done, the maintenance requirements to prevent those changes from disappearing get onerous.  (i.e. vendor update's their package, your changes risk disappearing).  Treating the vendor data as a base and then building on top of it, rather than modifying the base, actually makes your code much easier to maintain and work with.  IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend or customize the service providers if needed and then register them in your app config. For example, I recently needed to create my own password reset service provider.

First I created my 2 custom files in */app/Auth/Passwords/*

*PasswordResetServiceProvider.php*

```
namespace App\Auth\Passwords;

use App\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider as BasePasswordResetServiceProvider;

class PasswordResetServiceProvider extends BasePasswordResetServiceProvider 
{
    protected function registerPasswordBroker()
    {
        // my custom code here
        return new PasswordBroker($custom_things);
    }
}
```

*PasswordBroker.php*

```
namespace App\Auth\Passwords;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker as BasePasswordBroker;

class PasswordBroker extends BasePasswordBroker
{
    public function sendResetLink(array $credentials, Closure $callback = null) {
        // my custom code here    
        return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker::RESET_LINK_SENT;
    }

    public function emailResetLink(\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword $user, $token, Closure $callback = null) {
        // my custom code here
        return $this->mailer->queue($custom_things);
    }

}
```

**Now that I have my custom classes, I replaced the default service provider in my */config/app.php***

```
'providers' => [
    // a bunch of service providers

    // Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
    App\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class, //custom

    // the remaining service providers
],
```

There's probably another way to achieve the same result, but this was nice and easy.